# PySide6 line chart

Tags: python, charts, dashboard, pyside6, pyqt6

I'm developing a dashboard in Python (PySide6)to visualize data in real time.
I added a line chart like this example:

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_charts_linechart.html

Dashboarb is working, except for the line chart.

How do I automatically update the values ​​only on the Y axis?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.